# Which term describes best what is published in The Onion: "dry humour", "leg-pull", "kidding", "spin", "farce" or something else?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a term that describes the tongue-in-cheek trickery on the credulous and fairly dumb? The teasing activity of cooking up fake stories, hoaxes or ironical comments meant to be taken at face value and swallowed by the less discerning gull?

"Dry humour", "leg-pull", "kidding", "spin" or "farce" won't quite fit this description, will it?

Comment: Have you considered 'satire'?

Comment: Wikipedia says *The Onion is an American digital media company and newspaper organization that publishes **satirical** articles on international, national, and local news.*

Comment: ...elsewhere I find *The intended audience are **the more educated** who will appreciate **and understand** the satirical nature of the published artifacts. The Onion is **not intended for those under the age of 18.*** To put that another way, it's **NOT** "meant to be taken at face value and swallowed by the less discerning gull". (That's not a use of "gull" I'm familiar with, but Hey! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I was gulled by a used-car salesman once.

Comment: Thanks for inspiring me to go to The Onion. Ha ha ha ha!  'Pope Francis Declares Nothing Wrong With Guy Giving Buddy Tug Job After Few Drinks'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Even the *verb* form ***to gull*** sounds antiquated to me. The most recent citations for both noun and verb with this sense in the OED are well back in C19. My daughter tells me I was ***rinsed*** by cowboy workmen a few years back, but I dunno what the "derived noun victim" would be for that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - well, yes, Smollett, Sterne, Dickens, certainly. Rowling probably not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -  _wasted 30p using the toilets on King's Cross station. Later that day, I was gulled by my offspring into buying a Carambar sweet_ Zoe Williams, The Guardian, 5 April 2013; _I'm embarrassed to admit that I was gulled by the manufacturer's claim that an hour's sleep on a Tempur equated to three in a normal bed_ Charlotte Raven _Financial Times_ 26 November 2010

Comment: The Guardian has some peculiar writers on their books. I certainly wouldn't encourage *learners* to adopt that usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - we still talk about those 'gullible' people who fall for online  scams, don't we?

Comment: Sure - ***gullible*** remains "current". But look at [this usage shift.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+gulled%2Che+was+conned&year_start=1860&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) If not ***conned***, ***tricked*** or ***fooled*** or similar, but not normally ***gulled*** today. And that's *written* usage. I'm sure the decline of ***gulled*** is even more marked in *spoken* contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - in the UK, 'rinsing' can be something that attractive younger people do to older persons who are infatuated with them; the idea is to extract the maximum quantity of cash, expensive gifts, etc.

Comment: "**gulled by my offspring**" is obviously "facetious" phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of what is published in The Onion could be considered *satire*, but they also have some content that might be better described as *spoof* or *parody* news items.

The line between what is 'satire', 'parody', or a 'spoof' is often very thin, and some material could easily fall under more than one category. As a general rule though, 'satire' (defined as *literary work in which human foolishness or vice is attacked through irony, derision, or wit*) usually has some grounding in reality. An article about real people or events but which mocks some element of them through means such as exaggeration or introducing an element which is fabricated for the purpose of humour would be a satire - for example, if an Onion article told a story about a real politician in a fabricated situation for the purpose of creating a humourous outcome which was perhaps in-character for that politician and made an observation about their character.

On the other hand, I have read articles in the Onion which are entirely made-up - fabricated characters in fabricated events - and some might not consider these to be satire. Although it could be argued that the Onion satirises the manner in which mainstream media reports on events, so others may feel that even an article which says nothing about real people or events, if sending up the media coverage of such material, is still satire. Personally, I consider such material to be a "spoof" of the news, as there really is no way of saying how the media would cover material that has never even come close to happening. A 'spoof' news item is essentially a fake news item, but one created for humour or entertainment.

A 'parody' could be described as lying somewhere in between satire and spoof. Parodies often involve fabricated characters or events but which are recognisably similar to a real person or a real event. For example, if you read a story about an imaginary businessman who was incredibly successful, owned many large businesses and buildings, and had ambitions to become the president of the United States, you would instantly think that it was parodying a certain real-life person with a similar background and ambitions.

In many countries, there are laws protecting very specific types of satire and parody, so you may find a legal definition more helpful than a dictionary one.

Comment: *Parody* normally refers to replicating the style of a literary or musical work, not merely facts. We can parody the style of a politician's speeches, but not their life story (unless someone has written a biography of them with well known stylistic quirks).

Comment: A couple of examples: Weird Al Yankovic's work is parody. Philip Roth's *Our Gang*, which covers the life of President Trick E. Dixon, is satire.

Comment: @ThePhoton The Onion replicates the style of mainstream media, so in a sense it is a parody of media. But sometimes the subjects it deals with are real, and so takes a satirical look at them. 'News satire' is sometimes defined as a *type of parody*. However, satire stands alone as a method of looking at things such as news events, politics, current affairs etc. This is why I said from the outset that the lines can become very blurred.

Comment: I agree it is a parody of the media. But a story about a businessman who becomes president is not a parody of the businessman, unless it is presented in a style that simulates his writing or speaking style. (When Saturday Night Live presents fake speeches by actors representing the businessman, that is a parody of the businessman)

Comment: @ThePhoton We could argue all day, but it all comes down to how 'recognisable' it is as a parody. This an old example, but the character Daniel Clamp in the movie *Gremlins 2* is widely acknowledged as a parody of Donald Trump based on the similarity of the name, his position in the business world, buildings based in NYC etc... but there are almost no recognisable character traits of the man. I would argue that Clamp is a recognisable *parody* based on the similarities, but not a satire because the differences mean it says nothing about him.

Comment: Yes - ***spoof*** is the watchword here